# Conditions of change of variables for multiple integrals

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

As the conditions for transformation of multiple integrals, many textbooks state two separate conditions (along with other conditions):
(1) the transformation is 1-1
(2) The Jacobian does not vanish

For example, Courant and John in "Introduction to Calculus and Analysis" state:

> If the transformation $x=\phi(u,v), y=\psi(u,v)$ represents a continuous 1-1 mapping of the closed Jordan-measurable region $R$ of the $x,y$-plane on a region $R'$ of the $u,v$-plane, and if the functions $\phi$ and $\psi$ have continuous first derivatives and their Jacobian
> $$\frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)}=\phi_u \psi_v-\psi_u\phi_v$$
> is everywhere different from zero, then
> $$
>  \iint_R f(x,y)dxdy=\iint_R f(\phi(u,v),\psi(u,v))\left|\frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)}\right|du dv
> > $$

or Zill and Wright in "Advanced Engineering Mathematics":

> - The functions f and g have continuous first partial derivatives on S.
> - The transformation is one-to-one.
> - Each of the regions R and S consists of a piecewise-smooth simple closed curve and its iterior
> - The determinant
>   $$
>     \begin{vmatrix}
>      \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial x}{\partial v}\\
>      \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial u} & \dfrac{\partial y}{\partial v}
>      \end{vmatrix}
>      $$
>   is not zero on $S$.

If the transformation is $C^1$, doesn't "$J\neq 0$ within the interior of the preimage region" imply that the transformation is 1-1? or doesn't being 1-1 imply that $J\neq 0$?

Why are they stating these as two separate conditions?

---

PS: Bartle in "Elements of Real Analysis" states the theorem as follows:

> Suppose $\phi$ is in Class $C'$ on an open subset $G$ of $\mathbb{R}^p$ with values in $\mathbb{R}^p$ and that the Jacobian $J_\phi$ does not vanish on $G$. If $D$ is a compact subset of $G$ which has content and if $f$ is continuous on $\phi(D)$ to $R$, then $\phi(D)$ has content and
> $$\int_{\phi(D)} f=\int_D (f\circ\phi)|J_\phi|.$$

As we can see here Bartle does not talk about the fact that $\phi$ is a one-to-one onto mapping.

Comment: Consider $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x,y) = (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$. Is this function injective? What is the determinant of the Jacobian matrix?  Next, consider $g:\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $g(t) = t^3$. Again, is $g$ injective? Is the derivative everywhere non-zero? If you answer these questions carefully, then you'll realize why the two conditions are not at all equivalent.

Comment: As far as I know, $J\neq 0$ at some point $p$ does imply that the function is $1-1$ on some sufficiently small neighborhood about $p$ (assuming it's $C^1$). But it is not necessary that that the function be $1-1$ everywhere even if $J\neq 0$ everywhere (see peek-a-boo's comment).

Comment: @peek-a-boo we know that if $T:R'\to R$ and $|DT(u,v)|\neq 0$ for any $(u,v)\in R'$ and if $T$ maps the boundary of $R'$ in a 1-1 and onto manner to the boundary of $R$, then $T$ is 1-1 and onto from $R'$ to $R$. Which condition has be violated here? the boundary? For the second example, it is ok if T' is zero at isolated points.